# Is it possible to change the tooltip delay for files in Explorer on Windows 7 or 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-explorer, tooltip

In Explorer, one can view tooltips for files by hovering over them, as below:

[image]

This tooltip can show some helpful information, such as full file names which are too long for the current Name column width:

[image]

Note that this appears to be a separate mechanism entirely to tooltips on the rest of the Explorer frame. The following tooltips appear much more quickly, and, on my system at least, **do not require the window to be focussed** (whereas the 'file tooltips' do):

[image]

I would like to change the delay on the **file** tooltip (to be much shorter). **Is this possible?**

Comment: Try in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse` to set the item `MouseHoverTime` to a lower value, then reboot.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only pertains to tooltips such as those on the icons by the taskbar tray. I only made this post after a pretty thorough look around, and that was one of the things I noticed! As a note, the delay (400 ms by default) is about that of the 'frame' tooltips in Explorer, whereas the file tooltips take much longer to appear, and so are probably something else.

Comment: This is the only known mouse hover delay setting. If it doesn't pertain, I'm not sure that there is an answer to your question.

Comment: Fingers crossed someone out there knows of an undocumented feature, or at least can offer an explanation of how Explorer *does* do tooltips (in a way which is hard-coded or otherwise can't be changed without a mod). Thanks for pitching in, though.